# Azure DevOps Bug disappearing from board when marked as "Active"

Tags: azure-devops, bug-tracking, cmmi

I have been tasked with running point on implementing Azure DevOps on my team at work.

We are using the CMMI process and tracking bugs at the requirement level.

Recently, it was brought to my attention that when we marked a Bug work item as active, manually change the state and not drag the card to the next swimlane, it simply disappears from the board.  The work item can still be viewed on the task board, but is no where to be found on the requirements board until the state is changed again.

Has anyone else run into this problem and know of a fix?

Thanks

Comment: Moving to "Bugs are managed with tasks" means you lose the ability to manage a bug with multiple tasks. How can someone manage bugs as multiple tasks and keep them showing up on the Kanban board is the question.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is the configuration of the board itself. The default does not include bugs, so when you create your columns, the bug configuration for "Develop" gets set incorrectly.

Go to your settings for your board by clicking the gear icon in the upper-right of the board

[image: Click the gear]

Once into the settings, choose "Columns" from the list of items on the left of the modal window and then choose the column where the Bug items keep disappearing (the Develop column in my case), and you'll see some drop-downs for Bugs and Stories for "State Mapping".

[image: Default configuration]

If you change the bug setting here to "Active" and then save, the bugs should reappear on your Develop board. You'll want to do the same check for any other columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can update [Working with bugs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/show-bugs-on-backlog?view=azure-devops#set-your-teams-preferences-for-tracking-bugs) setting for boards to Bugs are managed with tasks.
You will need team administrator or a project administrator permissions to change this setting:

[image]